# How to manage data that change rarely on DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I developed a webservice that returns a List of objects.
These objects are read from the DB (no EF), and are retrieved by the user.
Moreover, this list of objects is requested by several other modules.

I think that in the same day, the 95% of the calls receive the same set of result, as the entities change rarely.
Anyway, I need to go to the DB and queries this data.

Is there a way, pattern or approach I can use to store in memory this set, and go to the DB only when someone notify me that something has been changed?

Technologies: webapi2 (service tier), c# 3.5 (logic tier and database access).

Thanks!
Roberto

Comment: You can use memory cache for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks @KosalaW. Can you add some details? 
Actually, my doubts/ lack of knowledge regards in particular how to be aware of the change of the actual data, in order to query again the DB and update the data

Comment: @KosalaW moreover seems that this is available only for net4 and later

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Just noticed you wanted something in 3.5. Is there a reason why you cannot upgrade it to 4.5?

Comment: @KosalaW: np. unfortunately 3.5 is a constrain with the legacy software I'm interacting with